# QueryWorkingSetEx returning invalid pages when applied to shared memory

Tags: windows, memory, shared

I'm creating a block of shared memory using CreateFileMapping and MapViewOfFile thus obtaining a pointer. I then apply QueryWorkingSetEx to to it, the problem is that i keep getting invalid pages in the PSAPI_WORKING_SET_EX_INFORMATION return structure. I'm on a NUMA architecture however the same thing happens on other non-NUMA machines.
If i try the exact same procedure on memory allocated with malloc and get valid results, is it possible that QueryWorkingSetEx does not support shared memory pointers?

Answer (score 1):

after talking with Microsoft's support i was given the solution for this, since QueryWorkingSetEx is being called immediately after MapViewOfFile the memory address hasn't yet been touched so the pages are not yet backed by any physical memory. 
The solution is to simply do a read loop over the memory address before QueryWorkingSetEx is invoked, this forces the memory manager to back up the pages with physical memory.

Comment: This is documented on the [VirtualQuery MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366902(v=vs.85).aspx) instead of the QueryWorkingSet page, somehow.